# The type initializer for 'NHibernate.LoggerProvider' threw an exception

Tags: nhibernate, common.logging

I am trying to use the Common.Logging assembly to replace the default nHibernate Log4net logging.

I added a reference in my project to: 
Common.Logging.dll v2.0 
NHibernate.Logging.CommonLogging.dll v1.2.0.4000

 and then added the following to my Web.config:

```
<add key="nhibernate-logger" value="NHibernate.Logging.CommonLogging.CommonLoggingLoggerFactory, Hibernate.Logging.CommonLogging"/>
```

My ulitmate goal is to replace the Log4net logging with the Enterprise Library 5.0, but I'm just taking it one step at a time at the moment.

When I run my app now I get the following exception:

```
The type initializer for 'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration' threw an exception. =>
The type initializer for 'NHibernate.LoggerProvider' threw an exception. =>
The type initializer for 'NHibernate.LoggerProvider' threw an exception. =>
Unable to instantiate: =>
Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: type
 at NHibernate.LoggerProvider.LoggerFor(Type type)
 at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration..cctor()
```

Is there anything that I'm missing to use the Common.Logging with nHibernate? I've tried following the instructions I've found on the web but it's not working and I can't find a solution :(

I'm using NHibernate v3.2.0.4000.

PS. This is my very first post on this site so sorry if the formatting is not right, I will glady accept constructive criticism :o)

Comment: I wish this question was answered. This is the same exact problem I am having

Comment: It is answered, just he didn't mark it.  One of the throwaway accounts, just made to ask one question.  Basically, the config string is copied from a tutorial, and it has a typo.  `"..., Hibernate.Logging."`.  It should be `NHibernate.Logging`

Answer (score 8):

switch *Hibernate.Logging.CommonLogging* with **N***Hibernate.Logging.CommonLogging*

Comment: I think we followed the same web how-to, and ended up copying his typo into our own config.

Answer (score 3):

try installing the NHibernate.Logging package from NuGet (or referencing the library, if you don't use NuGet). Worked for me.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your solution on windows server 2008, and using NHibernate 3.0+, make sure you have .Net 3.5 installed and that `aspnet_regiis` has been executed for .net framework (or frameworkx64) 2.0. Also if it is a website, make sure it is running on classic .net app pool and not the default app pool.

NHibernate 3.0+ needs .net 3.0 and above.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Version**

Check if your project's Assembly Name matches the value in the `nhibernate-logger` key in your `web.config`

**Long Version**

This is an old question, but I came across it when I had the same error. In my case the problem was caused because I renamed the project where the `NLogFactory` was located and changed the `web.config` to reflect that, but forgot to change the project's assembly name.

That is, I renamed my project from `CDP.Core` to `ARR.Code`, went into my `web.config` to change

```
<add key="nhibernate-logger" value="CDP.Core.DBContext.Framework.NLogFactory, CDP.Core" />
```

To:

```
<add key="nhibernate-logger" value="ARR.Core.DBContext.Framework.NLogFactory, ARR.Core" />
```

But forgot to go into the project properties, "Application" tab, and change "Assembly name" to the new name.